# how to determine server specification for webserver and mysql database server

Tags: linux, web-server, specifications

is there any formula to identify server specification base on simultaneous access, or something else. my manager need reasonable answer..

Comment: How much eight does a car need to carry? ;) Guess what - differs by driver (and habits). So, some websites are low resoruce usage, some are not. Profile it.

Answer (score 5):

Since we're extremely short on details:

Run a test server in a development/VM environment and extrapolate.

Comment: +1, Darn, you beat me to it.

Comment: Came for the snarky responses, but instead the first answer was sensible and polite.... You got my vote.